# Set margin-left and margin-right and keep vertical margin

Tags: css, html, layout, sass

Is there any way to set horizontal margin and inherit the vertical margin? Other way than to set `margin-left` and `margin-right`? I hoped for something like `margin: inherit 20px;` to work.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/cm8kwfok/1/

**Html**:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner horizontal-margin-working">
        Working but lame
    </div>
    <div class="inner horizontal-margin-notworking">
        Not working
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**:    .outer {
        background: #27ae60;
        padding: 10px;
    }

```
.inner {
    margin: 10px;
}

.horizontal-margin-working {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.horizontal-margin-notworking {
    margin: inherit 50px;
}
```

Comment: Replace `inherit` with `auto`.

Comment: Hey, this actually works. Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @MartinGottweis: No, it wouldn't. If you closely inspect the element you'd see that `auto` is different (try increasing the `margin: 10px` to say 100px). `auto` would set the `margin-top` and `margin-left` to some suitable value based on calculations but not to 10px (Which I assume is what you intended based on *keep* vertical margin. If not then sorry, my mistake).

Comment: @Roy: I don't think you understand what auto means.

Comment: @Harry oh, right, it doesn't work in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to ***keep*** the vertical margins when using the short-hand property. That is because:

- In CSS, when two or more selectors are applicable for an element, the values that are provided in the latest selector (or more specific selector) wins for common properties. Here, `margin` is given both in `.inner`, the other class  selector and so the one within `.inner` will get ***overwritten***.
- `inherit` (along with a length value) doesn't seem to be valid for the shorthand `margin` property whereas it is valid for the longhand `margin-*` properties and when `inherit` alone is specified in the shorthand. Moreover, `margin: 10px` is set in the `.inner` selector which is actually the same element (and not the parent), so `inherit` won't work.
- `auto` is a valid value for `margin` but it does not ***keep*** the margin specified in a previous selector. It tells the UA to calculate and assign a suitable value. For your case, it may set the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `10px` but it may not also (depending on other factors).
- When any length value (pixel or percentage) is given for the `margin` property, the UA decides on how to interpret the given value based on the no. of values provided. If one value is provided, that gets set to all sides, 2 values means first is vertical while second is horizontal margin and so on.

So, in short, overriding the `margin-left` and `margin-right` specifically (like in `.horizontal-margin-working`) is the only way you can get to ***keep*** the vertical margin.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `margin:inherit 50px;`

use like this

```
.horizontal-margin-notworking {
    margin-top: inherit;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<style>
.outer {
  background: #27ae60;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
  margin: 10px;
}

.horizontal-margin-working {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.horizontal-margin-notworking {

margin-top: inherit;
margin-bottom: inherit;
margin-left: 50px;



}

</style>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner horizontal-margin-working">
    Working but lame
  </div>
  <div class="inner horizontal-margin-notworking">
    Not working
  </div>
</div>
```